# in Emacs, how to change key bindings for orgstruct-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use custom key bindings for org-mode:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
'(progn
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-up>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-down>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-right] 'org-shiftmetaright)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-left] 'org-shiftmetaleft)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-right] 'org-metaright)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-left] 'org-metaleft)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-up] 'org-metaup)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-down] 'org-metadown)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-return] 'org-insert-todo-heading)
 ))
```

I'd like to use these same key bindings in orgstruct-mode, which I run overtop message-mode. What I tried doesn't work:

```
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-left>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-right>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-up>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-down>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-up>") nil)
 (define-key orgstruct-mode-map (kbd "<M-down>") nil)
```

How can I change the key map for orgstruct-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a key to `nil` unbinds it.  By unbinding a key in `orgstruct-mode-map` (the minor mode), you've exposed the `message-mode-map` (the major mode) bindings.  You can override the `message-mode-map` keybindings by actively binding those keys in `orgstruct-mode-map`, but if you want to *unbind* them, you'll need to unbind the keys in `message-mode-map` as well.

Here's a way to unbind all of those keys in both maps:

```
(cl-dolist (map '(message-mode-map orgstruct-mode-map))
  (cl-dolist (key '("<M-S-left>" "<M-S-right>" "<M-S-up>" "<M-S-down>"
                    "<M-left>" "<M-right>" "<M-up>" "<M-down>"))
    (define-key (eval map) (kbd key) nil)))
```

Comment: I put this in my .emacs but it seems to work only if I eval it manually. Do I have to wrap it in some kind of eval-after-load code?